# Collision using Reduced mass

Tags: collision

While reading a [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_mass#Collisions_of_particles) about collision using reduced mass I came across this.

[image: collision of particles]
how has it been derived?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Philip  I tried writing KE. of a system using reduced mass. which would contain (KE)of com. and 1/2(mu)vrel^2 but I dont know where to introduce the collision factor.

Comment: @shreya you need to format using math Jax. Search [math Jax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say there are 2 masses with velocities $u_1,u_2$. Let's define the relative velocity $v$ as $v = u_1-u_2$. Let's also define $$(1)\Delta K = \frac{1}{2}\mu (v_{final}^2 - v_{initial}^2)$$  and use the Coefficent of restitution definition $e = |\frac{v_{final}}{v_{initial}}|$ where $v_{initial}$ and $v_{final}$ are the velocities before and after a collision between the two masses, respectively.

If we multiply and divide (1) by $v_{initial}^2$, we get:
$$ \Delta K = \frac{1}{2}\mu v_{initial}^2 [(\frac{v_{final}}{v_{initial}})^2 -1 ]$$
We can now substitute $e$ in to finally get the desired expression for the change in kinetic energy:
$$ \Delta K = \frac{1}{2}\mu v_{initial}^2 [e^2 -1 ]$$